# augular-ui-router state will not match with query parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm stuck.

I can't get ui-router for AngularJS to match a state with a query parameter, but my other state with query parameters is working correctly.

Here is the problem state.

```
    $stateProvider.state(
        {
            name: 'sources-show',
            url: '^/sources/{id:[0-9]+}/:key?page&channel',
            controller:  ctrlFunc,
            templateUrl: 'Boards.Show'
        }
    );
```

The following URL will match.

```
http://example.com/sources/100/title
```

But this URL will trigger an `otherwise()` in `$urlRouterProvider`.

```
http://example.com/sources/100/title?channel=test
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. What's more this other state works perfectly fine.

```
    $stateProvider.state(
        {
            name:        'sources',
            url:         '^/sources?page&find',
            controller:  controller,
            templateUrl: 'Boards.By.Type'
        }
    );
```

The only thing I can conclude is that you can't mix query parameters with URL parameters.

Comment: Is `sources-show` a child state of `sources`? If so use a `.`  I dont think you can use Hypens. Angular as a pattern turns hypens into lower camel case, and u may be running into a compile time error. Anythung from your console or from Batarang?

Comment: @meze thanks tried it but didn't work.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch not a child state, and removing the `-` didn't fix it.

Comment: anyone know if there is a way to log all the compiled urlMatchers from ui-router?

Comment: Maybe it's the browser's cache? The example works fine for me.

Comment: @meze ah, good. It must be something else I've done.

Comment: @meze OMG! I had a trailing backslash on my URLs `http://example.com/sources/100/test/?channel=test` and didn't notice it.

Comment: In the next release we're rolling out a non-strict mode that you can use to allow routes to match URLs with or without trailing slashes.